# Place sprites at certain positions using a shader

Tags: fragment-shader, godot, godot-shader-language

##### What I achieved:

I **created a shader** (based on [this](https://godotshaders.com/shader/texture-population-using-texture/) code with this [plant asset](https://pop-shop-packs.itch.io/wild-plants-pixel-asset-pack)) that **takes a black and white reference image** (like a height map) and **places plants** on a grid determined by the **darkness/lightness-value** of the respective pixel.

[image: Black and white image to plants]

##### Where I am stuck:

I am trying to get a **more organic look** (instead of looking like a tileset) so I used **[poisson-disc-sampling](https://github.com/udit/poisson-disc-sampling)** to get random-looking coordinates for **where I want to place the plants**. In "normal" code I'd just loop through the array of the generated coordinates and draw a sprite ... but I have no clue how to do that with a shader.

[image: Approach using poisson-disc-sampling]

##### Question:

**Is it even possible to use a shader to place images at certain positions?**
(I could obviously generate a static image but I am planning to adjust the shader to simulate wind going over the vegetation [like this](https://john-wigg.dev/2DGrassShaderDemo/))

Thanks already in advance for any tip or help!

Comment: This is not possible *directly*, there might be a way but it would take multiple render passes, and I can't fully imagine it right now. Instead I'm going to suggest to use a particle system.

Comment: @Theraot Thanks for your assessment and the recommendation regarding a particle system. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how you might do it using your poisson disc sampling approach.  However, you could generate a random number between 0 and 1 and modify the line `vec2 source_uv = (floor(coord) + 0.5) * cell_scale;` in your shader code to be `vec2 source_uv = (floor(coord) + rand(vec2(TIME, 0.0)) * cell_scale;`.  

A random function like:

```float rand(vec2 co){
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}``` 

should do it.  Obviously, modify it until you get what you want.

Comment: @HumanWrites Thanks for the idea! 
As it seems that a shader might not be the correct approach for what I am trying to achieve, I also did some research and maybe "normal" drawing [with proper batching](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/performance/batching.html) might do the trick too. Haven't tested it yet, though.